# Outlook checking wrong autoconfiguration URI

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange-2010

I have a problem with a single user who cannot set their `OOF`.

Further investigations of his autoconfiguration test (right click Outlook in system tray and Test Email Autoconfiguration) have shown it's not looking at the correct URI

On the server if I run `Get-ClientAccessServer | Select Name, *Internal* | fl` it gives me `https://remote.<domain>.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml` whereas Outlook is looking at `https://<domain>.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml` and `https://autodiscover.<domain>.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml`

Because of this, it is never receiving the OOF URL.

How can I change the autoconfiguration on the client side? This is only affecting one user so I don't want to change the CAS settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I didn't think of adding the URL it was trying and failing with to the host file using the external IP address. This solved it.